# Android SharedPreferences Boolean not working

Tags: android, boolean, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to get a **boolean** value from **SharedPreferences** that is **true** but I'm getting a **false** value every time.
The SharedPreferences file named "MyPref"contains the following code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<boolean name="PREMIUM" value="true" />
</map>
```

I'm adding values to SharedPreferences in **MyActivity.class** using the following code:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 1); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("PREMIUM", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
editor.commit(); // commit changes
Log.d(TAG, "User is " + (mIsPremium ? "PREMIUM" : "NOT PREMIUM"));
```

And retrieving it on **multiple classes** by using:

```
boolean mIsPremium = false;
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 1); // 0 - for private mode
mIsPremium = pref.getBoolean("PRIVATE", false); // getting boolean
Log.d("IS PREMIUM", String.valueOf(mIsPremium));
if(mIsPremium) {
    // PREMIUM USER - NO ADS
} else {
    // NOT PREMIUM USER - SHOW ADS
}
```

I'm always getting the value of **Premium** as **false**, what could be the reason for this to happen and how to solve it ? I'm using android 4.2.2. Thank you all.

Comment: Why you are using 1 as Flag. and different keys to get and store boolean?

Comment: on store premium, but when get private why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
mIsPremium = pref.getBoolean("PREMIUM", false);
```

NOT `("PRIVATE",false)`

You are using different keys, they need to match.

Comment: I'm been been working a lot and because of that I've missed the basic ... Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: It happens to everyone, especially on friday :) Happy to help.

Comment: You did, I'm waiting one minute to mark your answer and the correct one :)

Answer (score 2):

SharedPrefernces are saved in key:value pairs ,you are putting value in "PREMIUM" and retreiving as "PRIVATE"

Answer (score 1):

You changed keys "PREMIUM" and "PRIVATE". Using of hardcoded strings is a generally bad programming practice. I would recommend using final static variables for these.