# stopping toast android in other actvity

Tags: java, android, android-toast

my problem is this:

I make a toast "welcome" in the Activity Main for the first time that you open the home, and it's ok,but when another page to return to the home via the back button, how can I make the toast "welcome" does not appear anymore?

the code of main activity is:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
MyActivity actvi1;
int cont=0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);





    Button btnabout=(Button)findViewById(R.id.about);

    //click

    btnabout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // definisco l'intenzione di aprire l'Activity "aboutme.java"

            Intent aboutmejava= new Intent(MyActivity.this,aboutme.class);

            startActivity(aboutmejava);
        }

    }

    );


    //toast

       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
               "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 20, 0);
       toast.show();
```

code of aboutme.java

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aboutme);

    Button btnback=(Button)findViewById(R.id.scritta);

    btnback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent main = new Intent(aboutme.this,MyActivity.class);

            startActivity(main);
```

Comment: so you want to make this toast appears only the first time you run your application?

Comment: yes, exactly 
when I go back to the home should not appear. 
Only the first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
    SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int show = sp.getInt("firstlaunch", 0);
    if(show == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WELCOME", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        sp.edit().putInt("firstlaunch", 1).apply();
    }
```

Place it in your home activities onCreate method.'

A shared preference is a "setting" of sort. It's a xml file that is loaded which contains all of your settings. When we first run "sp.getInt" you can see that i have a 0 after the "key - fistlaunch". The 0 is specifying what to give our Int SHOW if it can't find any shared preference with that key. Next if the int show is equal to 0 we run our Toast and then change the shared preference value to 1 so next time you run it doesn't show...

Comment: At least inform the OP what that code actually does instead of claiming "it works"

Comment: Java is pretty self explanatory. BUT i will, for you.

Comment: Not for me. I know what it does. But the OP didn't ask for shared preferences. So if you're going to give a solution with it at least explain why. And also `SharedPreferences` is not `Java` as you're saying.

Comment: SharedPreference is a Java class that is a part of the android API. Nothing is just "java" unless your talking about the raw code. It's composed of a toolset of classes (and native methods) that create what we know as the SDK. which i'm referring to of course, the Android SDK.

Comment: in this case I run the toast just the first time I launch the app, but if I close and reopen the beginning do not execute the toast.

Comment: "firstlaunch" is always set to 1, why?

Comment: So you want the toast to run every time you start the app but not everytime your activity calls onCreate() -- in other words. When you start the app it runs but when you go between activities in your app it doesnt run?

Comment: no, the toast start only the first time I launch the app. if I close and reopen the app, the toast does not appear, I have to make a clear Cache to restart it

Comment: Is that what you want or do you want it to appear every time you start the app? Clearing the cache clears your SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to *only show the very first time* the application runs, put a `boolean` flag in `SharedPreferences` and check here. There are tons of examples but [here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487101/android-sharedpreferences-boolean-not-working)

If you want it to show *every time the Activity is first run when the app starts, simply replace your `onClick()` code with `onBackPressed()`. This way it won't start a new instance of your `MyActivity` and since the `Toast` code is in `onCreate()` and not `onResume()`, it won't run when you go back by clicking the back button.

[SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Answer (score 0):

```
   boolean b = false;
if(!b) {
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 20, 0);
toast.show();
b = true
}
```

kind of like that?

Comment: I mean putting the boolean b = false in the beginning of the class(think thats called global, right?), should have mentioned that :P

Answer (score 0):

Are you another instance of MainActivity?
In order to return to your Main activity you should send an Intent with the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP (or set  android:launchMode="singleTop" in launchMode in AndroidManifest.xml)

```
 Intent main = new Intent(aboutme.this,MyActivity.class);
 main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(main);
```

By doing so, your main activity will be restored, instead of creating a new instance of MainActivity